# Unable to generate apk file using NDK in eclipse

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I've been trying to write a simple android app using NDK in Eclipse IDE.

- Added NDK plug in
- Added jni folder in the project and written a Cpp code
- Built it properly using ndk-build
- so file(s) are also generated

Compilation was successful and error-free. Yet, I'm unable to run it as an Android App as the apk file hasn't been generated.

Kindly help :)

Comment: is `.so` file is generated in `libs->armeabi` folder ?

Comment: Yes. It is generated.

Comment: I think you should post your LogCat message. What is actual problem, is `.so` is not loaded in memory of device, or its crashing, or any other problem ?

Comment: No no..so is loaded fine. But apk file is not generated.

It shows 'No apk file found' in the console, when I run it as 'Android Application'

Comment: Clean your project `Project->Clean` and
Go to `Build Path->Configur Build Path` and Change the `Default Output folder` path. Not sure but it may help.

Comment: Or you can point out what is exact problem then it will be better to any solution.

Comment: Yeah. I've configured ndk-build as the builder for the code. The problem is, I'm unable to get the apk file generated as it does for SDK.! Thanks btw for your patience. :)